# Combe Rectangle and Vector movement

Tags: monogame

I'm completely fresh to game development and came up to a problem which I'm not sure how to solve. I have textures which are quite too big for screen. So i used SpriteBatch.Method which uses rectangle as parameter which allows me to get custom size of texture. But I need as well Vector position for movement to specific direction. So I used method which uses Vector position and float scale to make it smaller. And now I can't check really if it Intersects with other objects or simple width, height properties. It seems that I cannot pass both vector position and rectangle as well. Isn't there a way to specify just a rectangle for texture's height/width to be rendered and vector for position?

Comment: Your drawing and game logic should be separated. Your draw loop should adapt to the way your objects are represented. If your game objects are rectangles- find a way the drawing can accomodate that. As @Paste answered there are overloads that do exactly as you need (even one that takes a source rect and destination rect as parameters).

Answer (score 1):

There are three overloads of the `SpriteBatch.Draw()` method available that will suit you:

```
SpriteBatch.Draw (Texture2D, Vector2, Nullable<Rectangle>, Color)
SpriteBatch.Draw (Texture2D, Vector2, Nullable<Rectangle>, Color, Single, Vector2, Single, SpriteEffects, Single)
SpriteBatch.Draw (Texture2D, Vector2, Nullable<Rectangle>, Color, Single, Vector2, Vector2, SpriteEffects, Single)
```

In each case, the second parameter is a `Vector2` representing the location on the screen where the texture should be drawn, and the third parameter is a (nullable) `Rectangle` that represents the portion of the texture to be drawn. You can read more about them at the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritebatch.draw.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If the rectangle is where you want the picture to be drawn (destination rectangle), rather than the part of the texture you wish to draw (source rectangle), then a better answer would be to recreate the rectangle whenever the object moves using the vector2.

For example:

```
//movement code here
rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.x, (int)position.y, width, height);
```

That will put the position vector2 in the top left hand corner. You can put it in the centre by:

```
rectangle = new Rectangle(
  (int)(position.x - (width/2)),
  (int)(position.y - (height/2)), width/2, height/2);
```